# How to recover the alias of an email address (Outlook) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, outlook, alias

I developed an application which allows me to manage emails via **Interop.Outlook**.

It works correctly however I need to recover from an email received the email addresses to which it was sent. I have an email address that has different aliases.

For example :

depot@mail.com -> this email address is my deposit address

client1@mail.com -> this is an email address with an alias given to the client 1

client2@mail.com -> this is an email address with an alias given to the client 2

When client 1 will send an email to client1@mail.com, I will therefore receive an email at depot@mail.com.
So I wonder how I can retrieve the alias client1 in my code ?

I did a lot of research and I found a code that allows me to display all the aliases of an email address but that does not allow me to specify which alias was used to send the email to the address deposit. the code in question can be found below :

```
  Dim recips As Recipients = oMsg.Recipients
  For Each recip As Recipient In recips
    ' oMsg is my MailItem
            If recip.Name = "depot" Then
                For i2 = 0 To 4
                    Console.WriteLine(recip.AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101F")(i2))
                    Console.WriteLine("************************************** " + i2.ToString)
                Next
            End If
  Next
```

If you have an idea, I'm interested :D Thank's in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a better way than what I came up with, but here it is.  If you look in to the InternetMessageHeaders on the Email message, it is buried there (at least it was for me).

```
                        For idx1 = 0 To msg.InternetMessageHeaders.Count - 1
                        If msg.InternetMessageHeaders.Item(idx1).Name = "Received" AndAlso msg.InternetMessageHeaders.Item(idx1).Value.Contains("@<the domain you have>.com") Then
                            Console.WriteLine(msg.Subject)
                            Console.WriteLine(idx1)
'It hides in the below value between <>, so I parsed it out.                                Console.WriteLine(msg.InternetMessageHeaders.Item(idx1).Value)
                                Dim front() As String = msg.InternetMessageHeaders.Item(idx1).Value.Split("<")
                                Dim back() As String = front(1).Split(">")
                                Dim toaddr As String = back(0)
                                Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf + toaddr)

                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
```